# Supervisor numproc resources / memory usage

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I am running a worker in Laravel with Supervisor. In the configuration i can spawn a number of processes `(numproc)`.

What is the recommended number of processes to start? I should just start 1 process right `(numproc=1)`? I am a bit confused how many processes i should start? What is the idea behind `numproc`

Why should i run the same worker simultaneously?

I tried to search in the docs, but i can't really find anything in depth about this topic.

Comment: IMHO the number of processes will depend on each application. For example, I set numproc > 1 for a single-threaded process that could only serve N requests/second. Not only it could achieve a higher ratio but system was more tolerant to failure of that component (if an instance crashed, there were still N-1 doing their job while being restarted).